# Anchor link for same and different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm using that code:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and `<a href="#allcontentcontact">` to link to the div `<div id="allcontentcontact"></div>`.

The problem is:
"#allcontentcontact" is on my homepage, so the code works perfectly only when I'm on the homepage. But I have a fixed menu that links to other pages! So I need something that makes my a href links to that div when I'm on another page.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: I think I posted all that matters. What else you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I did it! :)

```
<script>
var url = "http://192.168.1.157/wp/";
$(function(){
  if (location.href==url){
    $('#menu #mylink').attr("href","#bluecontent");
    $('#menu #mylink2').attr("href","#allcontentcontact");
  }
});
</script>
```

The URL is strange because I'm coding on localhost, but the code works perfectly. :)

And the HTML

```
<a id="mylink" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>#bluecontent"><span>Parceiros</span></a>

<a id="mylink2" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>#allcontentcontact"><span>Contato</span></a>
```

It's almost done. All the links works perfectly taking me smoothly to their specified anchors.

The problem is: my script that slides to anchors on other pages include the #bluecontent and #allcontentcontact on the URL. Is it possible to delete that from the URL? 
Here is the code:

```
var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   $('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },2000,function()
   {
       location.hash = target;
   });

}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
```